# Mootools .addClass won't work

Tags: css, mootools

I'm trying to `addclass` to another div on click but for some reason it won't work and I'm not getting any errors Javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
    $('ce-cf-container-18').addEvent('click', function(){ 
        $('progress').addClass('rotate'); 
    }); 
});
```

and CSS:

```css
#progress{
    top: 294px;
    left: 63px;
    height: 0px !important;
    width: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    border: 2px solid #232323;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.rotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

Comment: This code should work. Can you post a jsfiddle, so we can have a look at it in real usage, please?

Comment: My best guess is he has multiple elements with the `id` of "progress"...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is well written, what can be wrong is:

You are referring to `#ce-cf-container-18` and `#progress`. If these elements have id there cannot be more than one of each.

If some of them is should be referred by class instead you can use `document.getElements('.classname');`